# Scala - copy fields of a StructType results in 'cannot resolve symbol fields'

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, collections, apache-spark-sql

I'm filtering a StructType to leave only StructFields with specific names. But when using a `copy` method I'm getting errors when filtering fields: `cannot resolve symbol fields; cannot resolve symbol name.`

I've checked the `StructType` case class and confirmed that it has `fields` so I should be able to use a copy method.

What could be my mistake here?

```
def customSchema(originalStruct: StructType, updColumns: List[String]) = if (isFilteringReq) {
  updColumns  match {
    case List.empty => originalStruct
    case _ => originalStruct.copy(fields = fields.filter(f =>
      updColumns.contains(f.name)))
  }
}
```

**Sample input:**

```
val originalStruct = StructType(Array(
  StructField("metric_1", IntegerType,true), 
  StructField("metric_2", IntegerType,true), 
  StructField("metric_3", IntegerType,true),
  StructField("metric_5", IntegerType,true),
  StructField("metric_7", IntegerType,true),
))
 val isFilteringRequired = true 
 val specialColumnNames = List("metric_1", "metric_2", "metric_3")

val newSchema = produceCustomSchema(originalStruct, isFilteringRequired, specialColumnNames)
```

**Expected output:**

```
val newSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("metric_1", IntegerType,true), 
      StructField("metric_2", IntegerType,true), 
      StructField("metric_3", IntegerType,true)))
```

Comment: Can you show sample input and expected output?

Comment: @shanmuga added sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with your `customSchema` method:

1. Returning a `if` without `else` would make the return type `Any`
2. `fields` on the right hand side within `copy` needs to be specified as `originalStruct.fields`
3. `isFilteringReq` would better be included in the argument list

Below is a revised method with minimal changes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def customSchema(originalStruct: StructType, updColumns: List[String], isFilteringReq: Boolean) =
  if (isFilteringReq) updColumns match {
    case Nil => originalStruct
    case _   => originalStruct.copy(fields = originalStruct.fields.filter(f =>
      updColumns.contains(f.name)))
  } else
    originalStruct
```

Testing the method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 10, 20, 100.0),
  (2, 30, 40, 200.0)
).toDF("id", "metric_1", "metric_2", "price")

val isFilteringRequired = true 
val specialColumnNames = List("metric_1", "metric_2", "metric_3")

customSchema(df.schema, specialColumnNames, isFilteringRequired)
// res1: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
//   StructField(metric_1,IntegerType,false), StructField(metric_2,IntegerType,false)
// )
```

Comment: Thanks! This could be a little bit out of the scope of my question, but how can I apply the `customSchema` method to the existing schema? I can't do a .map() after the curly brace of the following StructType -  `val originalSchema: StructType = schemaType match {
  case "type_1" => getType1chema()
  case "type_2" => getType2chema()
}`

Comment: @samba, assuming `specialColumnNames` consists of only top-level columns, rather than using the custom schema a simpler way to generate the new DataFrame would be to conditionally `select` matching columns, like, `df.select(specialColumnNames.collect{case c if df.columns.contains(c) => col(c)}: _*)`.

Answer (score 1):

I see here:

originalStruct.copy(fields = **fields**.filter(f => updColumns.contains(f.name)))

that there is no variable called "fields"

if you need to modify originalStruct "fields" variable, you can do it this way:

```
originalStruct.copy(fields = originalStruct.fields.filter(f => updColumns.contains(f.name)))
```